# Download a sheet from Google with Python and the correct charset

Tags: python, python-requests, character-encoding, google-sheets-api

I used this Python script (thanks to Tanaike) to download a specific sheet in Google Spreadsheet as a CSV data:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
import requests

# Script for authorization of pydrive.
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

# Download the specific sheet in Google Spreadsheet as a CSV data.
spreadsheetId = '###' # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetId = '###' # Please set the sheet ID. (GID)
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetId + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + sheetId
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gauth.credentials.access_token}
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

the script works fine but in the CSV output I have a charset problem, I can't see accented characters.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. So can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for reply. I'm Italian so if I write in the sheet accented characters like àèìòù I can't see them in the output csv. Instead, if I download the CSV by the GUI of the page I can see accented characters...

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, when I added the text of `àèìòù` to the Spreadsheet and run the script, the created file can be seen as the correct inputted text. So, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the method for replicating your issue?

Comment: Thank you again Tanaike. I only insert the string and launch the script... Nothing else, I can't understand. Even if use the link via browser "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[fileid]/export?format=csv&gid=[sheetid]" I download the file without charset problems, but I don't how I can use this link in the script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modification point for changing the endpoint to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[fileid]/export?format=csv&gid=[sheetid]`. Could you please test it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and replying comments, when I added the text of `àèìòù` to the Spreadsheet and run the script in your question, the created file can be seen as the correct inputted text. So, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation.

And, from your following previous replying,

> Thank you again Tanaike. I only insert the string and launch the script... Nothing else, I can't understand. Even if use the link via browser "`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[fileid]/export?format=csv&gid=[sheetid]`" I download the file without charset problems, but I don't how I can use this link in the script.

When you want to change the endpoint from `'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetId + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + sheetId` to `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[fileid]/export?format=csv&gid=[sheetid]`, please modify the script as follows.

#### From:

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetId + '/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=' + sheetId
```

#### To:

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + spreadsheetId + '/export?format=csv&gid=' + sheetId
```

#### Note:

- In my environment, when I tested both endpoints, I could confirm that the correct inputted text including `àèìòù` can be seen.